# Why We Say Destructor Call When Object Goes out of Scope?

Tags: c++, destructor

I learned that the destructor is called when an object goes out of scope and also the destructor deletes the objects. Ok fine, but what's happening here?

I'm calling the destructor explicitly, if it deletes the object then why is the destructor implicitly called? Even though there no object now because it's already deleted with the explicitly destructor calling. Sorry may be I'm wrong about explicitly and implicitly But try to understand my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
    public:
        A(){
            cout << "Constructor" << endl;
        }
        ~A(){
            cout << "Destructor" << endl;
        }

};
int main(){
    A obj;
    obj.~A();
    cout << "End" << endl;
}
```

Now

```
obj.~A();
```

The above line deletes the object. Then why again is the destructor called? Even though no object is there.

Output:

```
Constructor
Destructor
End
Destructor
```

Comment: `obj.~A();` You don't ever call the destructor function manually, that leads to trouble.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But can you explain what's happening in my code? and why should not call destructor manually?

Comment: @Asif, you seem to be confused about what a destructor does. Specifically, it does *not* free the storage associated with the object. So it's wrong to write that `obj.~A()` *deletes* the object.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi this point that I was trying to clear. `Destructor not deletes the object when called.` Thanks

Comment: It isn't "do not ever call the destructor manually".  It is "only call the destructor manually if you are doing placement new on properly aligned storage prior to calling it, because you are writing a union-like or container type and manually managing object lifetime at a low level".  Admittedly that is really close to "never".

Comment: @Yakk thanks to participate I understood I should never call it manually when I write `delete[] ptr` etc in destructor. But can you also clear my confusion? `Destructor not deletes the object when it's called.` this line is fine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object which goes out of scope has its destructor called. That is an unchangeable guarantee which is mandated by the C++ language standard. It doesn't matter if you've manually called the destructor beforehand; when it goes out of scope, the destructor will be called. If you've written your destructor such that bad things happen if it's called twice, or if the extra behavior which the compiler inserts into the destructor code doesn't want to be called twice, bad things will happen.

This is one of many reasons why you should never manually call a destructor.

Comment: I understood I should never call it manually when I write `delete[] ptr` etc in destructor. But can you also clear my confusion? `Destructor not deletes the object when it's called with empty body`. this line is fine?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq No.  A destructor does _not_ delete the object, ever.  Deleting an object does call the destructor, but you should only delete an object that was allocated by `new`.  Explicitly calling the destructor is only used when the object has been constructed using placement new.

Answer (score 1):

Your object does not contain any pointers. It does not free any objects in the destructor when called so no harm is done when it is called multiple times.
If the destructor deletes pointers and those pointers are not set to 0, which is often the case in destructors, then the second call of the destructor would be harmful because it would cause a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor does *not* delete the object, it destructs it.
And unless the object is a POD type (basically, something you
could define in C), destructing an already destructed object is
undefined behavior.  Since all variables will automatically have
their destructor called when their lifetime ends, you should
never explicitly call the destructor on them.  Similarly, if you
have created the object with a non-placement form of `new`:
explicitly calling the destructor will not free the memory; you
should use `delete`, which calls the destructor and then frees
the memory.

The only time you should explicitly call the destructor is when
you have used placement new to construct the object, in order to
separate allocation and initialization.  Today, such techniques
should really be considered advanced, and it is rare for a
programmer to need them.

Answer (score 1):

Your provided class doesn't manage any data, so its destructor doesn't have any objects to free.  That's why you're able to call the destructor twice with no consequences.  Here's an example class that would fail the same test:

```
#include <iostream>


class A {
 public:
  A() {
    std::cout << "constructing..." << '\n';
    val = new int;
  }

  ~A() {
    std::cout << "destructing..." << '\n';
    delete val;
  }

 private:
  int* val;
};


int main() {
  A obj;
  obj.~A();
  std::cout << "End" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The constructor allocates space on the heap for `val`, and the destructor runs `delete` to free up that space.  `~A()` is called twice in `main()` (first explicitly, then implicitly), which understandably causes a memory error.

Check out this link for more info on how destructors work:
https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors

Comment: why you removed using namespace std; ? and used it separately ? any logic behind it?

Comment: It's just good practice.  Here's the generally accepted answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Although here it doesn't actually matter, since it's just an example program.